# Error message message on views.py to render register.html

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I am working on a project but i have stock on the views.py
when i run the code it keeps telling me error message like the one below

(django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'register.html' not found. 'register.html' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)

Am expecting the register.html to take effect instead of the index.html

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

## my views.

```
from .forms import CreateUserForm, LoginForm
```

## - Homepage

```
def home(request):
    
    return render(request, 'webapp/index.html')
```

## - Register a user

```
def register(request):

    form = CreateUserForm()

    if request.method == "POST":

        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            
            
            return redirect("my-login")


    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'webapp/register.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the webpage template for `index.html`.